# Provider dont update a data in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm create a project on Flutter. And I'm using a provider to change screens in my app.
Here is my main.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:school_app/services/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:school_app/wrapper.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => AuthService().auth,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also this is my wrapper.dart file where the screens choose:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:school_app/screens/authenticate/auth.dart';
import 'package:school_app/models/user.dart';
import 'package:school_app/screens/school/home.dart';
import 'package:school_app/services/auth_service.dart';

class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context); 
    print(user.auth);
    if(!user.auth) return Auth();
    return Home();
  }
}
```

And it is my AuthProvider class:

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class AuthService {


   /* AuthUser _user(User user) {
    return user != null ? AuthUser(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }*/

AuthProvider auth = new AuthProvider();

  //sign in
  Future signIn(String username, String password) async {
    try {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      var dio = Dio();
      Response user = await dio.post('url', data: {
        'username': username,
        'password': password
      });
      if(user.data['success'] == false) return user.data['msg'];
      await prefs.setString('token', user.data['token']);
      auth.setAuth(true);
      print("SUCCESS");
    } catch(e) {
      print('Error ' + e.toString());
    }
  }

}

class AuthProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _auth;

  AuthProvider() {
    _auth = false;
  }

  bool get auth => _auth;

  void setAuth(bool auth) {
    _auth = auth;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

And when I call a function in AuthProvider class setAuth, nothing changed. Can you help me and find my mistake?

**EDIT**

I'm making all changes that you writes but it is not working. Here is my main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:school_app/services/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:school_app/wrapper.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => AuthProvider(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also wrapper.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:school_app/screens/authenticate/auth.dart';
import 'package:school_app/screens/school/home.dart';
import 'package:school_app/services/auth_service.dart';

class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WrapperState createState() => _WrapperState();
}

class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    AuthService().auth;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AuthProvider>(builder: (context, authProvider, child) {
      print(authProvider.auth);
      if (!authProvider.auth) {
        return Auth();
      } else {
        return Home();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And AuthService and AuthProvider classes:

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class AuthService {


   /* AuthUser _user(User user) {
    return user != null ? AuthUser(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }*/

AuthProvider auth = new AuthProvider();

  //sign in
  Future signIn(String username, String password) async {
    try {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      var dio = Dio();
      Response user = await dio.post('url', data: {
        'username': username,
        'password': password
      });
      if(user.data['success'] == false) return user.data['msg'];
      await prefs.setString('token', user.data['token']);
      auth.setAuth(true);
      print("SUCCESS");
    } catch(e) {
      print('Error ' + e.toString());
    }
  }

}

class AuthProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _auth;

  AuthProvider() {
    _auth = false;
  }

  bool get auth => _auth;

  void setAuth(bool auth) {
    _auth = auth;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Notice, that here two classes and in AuthService I'm calling function .setAuth(true).

Answer (score 0):

The only missing part here is that you never Consume the AuthProvider to listen to the `notifyListeners()` trigger.
The correct implementation looks like the following (I didn't try it, you may have to correct some typo errors, but you'll get the idea !)

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AuthProvider>(
        builder: (context, authProvider, child) {
          if (!authProvider.auth) {
            return Auth();
          } else {
            return Home();
          }
        }

    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
I didn't notice you weren't injecting the right Class in your ChangeNotifierProvider.  You'll also have to update your widget MyApp

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => AuthProvider(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And in this case you probably should transform your `Wrapper` widget to a Stateful widget, and in the `initState` method you should call `AuthService().auth`.

I strongly recommend you to read the [official documentation of Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), looks like things aren't crystal clear yet in your mind

**EDIT 2**
You're still missing the point of the Provider library.

The goal of this lib is to provide an instance of a class to your widget tree so you don't have to re-create an instance in each widget.

Here, in `AuthService` class you're re-creating a AuthProvider with `AuthProvider auth = new AuthProvider();` instead of referring to the existing instance created in the parent Widget.

To refer to a previously created instance, you should use `Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);` in the AuthService class, or, even better, pass the instance of AuthProvider as a parameter in the signIn method.

Comment: @РостиславРоманец I edited my answer to fix another bug

Comment: I'm editing my question and there is a new code, but it still not working.

Comment: @РостиславРоманец added more details to the answer

Comment: Happy to read it !!! Don't forget to mark your question as answered, it may help someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

In your current implementation of `Wrapper`, you are rendering the widget once and not listening to whether the values changed. You could use Consumer as suggested above. You could also choose to `watch` the value for changes - like this:

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = context.watch<AuthProvider>();
    print(user.auth);
    if(!user.auth) return Auth();
    return Home();
  }
}
```

When you use a `watch` or `Consumer` pattern, the widget will be rendered when the values of the underlying store (which is AuthProvider here) gets changed.

Comment: In your main.dart update your changeNotifierProvider to be this: `ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AuthProvider()),`

Comment: I'm editing my question and there is a new code, but it still not working.